# Disable reply or forward in outlook using c#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm using c# outlook add-in.
How can I prevent reply or forward if sender address is something?

Comment: add description with code, this is not sufficient to understand the problem

Comment: @Pranav Patel, I don't have any code, I want to disable forward or reply buttons when an opened mail sender is a specific address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trap the MailItem.Reply / ReplyAll / Forward events. All of them have Cancel (by ref) parameter which you can set to true.

Comment: tnx for your reply.where and how should I define the events?Can you give me a sample please?

Comment: You will need to track the Explorer.SelectionChange event (retrieve the Explorer object from Application.ActiveExplorer), Keep the selected items in a list,  when SelectionChange fires, clear the collection (use Marshal.ReleaseComObject to make sure the items are released immediately so you don't get the same item firing twice before GC decided to release it), set up event handlers on all items from the hExplorer.Selection collection. When Reply/ReplyAll/Forward event fires, look at the sender and cancel the event if necessary.

Comment: If you (also) want to track the items displayed in inspectors. use the Application.Inspectors.NewInspector event  and set up event sinks on Isnpector.CurrentItem. Monitor Inspector.Close event to clear the items displayed in inspectors.

Answer (score 0):

you should use VBA macro.

check this link: 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToEasilyDisableReplyToAllAndForwardInOutlook.aspx

obviously, access to ActiveInspector can also be gained via the interops..

```
ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Reply").Enabled = False
ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Forward").Enabled = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to create an email and disallow the reply and reply all function using c# for a visual studio project. I came across your question, but the answer you marked didn't work for me. The following did what I was looking for, I hope it helps someone else looking for something similar:

```
 Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

 //Create new email
 Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

 //Set recipients here
 Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oMsg.Recipients.Add(myRecipientsVariable);

 //Check to make sure they're all valid recipients in my contact list
 oRecip.Resolve();

 //Stop recipients from being able to reply all
 oMsg.Actions["Reply to All"].Enabled = false;

 //Stop them from being able to reply
 oMsg.Actions["Reply"].Enabled = false;

 //Set the Subject line
 oMsg.Subject = "Test Subject Line";

 //Tidy Up
 oRecip = null;
 oMsg = null;
 oApp = null;
```

Basically the message.Actions[    ].enabled= false; bit. I believe this will work with any outlook 2013 and later.

-Cheers